# Template vs. ControlTemplate vs. DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

We have Templates, Control Templates and Data Templates for WPF controls.  I don't know if there exists any more types (please let me know if any).  But, when to use what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the `FrameworkTemplate` derived types:

- `ControlTemplate` - Specifies the visual structure and behavioral aspects of a `Control` that can be shared across multiple instances of the control.;
- `DataTemplate` - Describes the visual structure of a data object;
- `ItemsPanelTemplate` - Specifies the panel that the `ItemsPresenter` creates for the layout of the items of an `ItemsControl`.

P.S.: As you can see there is no just "Template" :)

Comment: There is no `Template` type, but the `ControlTemplate` is assigned to the `Template` property (e.g. `Button.Template`) inherited from `Control`.

Answer (score 1):

[HierarchicalDataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx)

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:League}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Divisions}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:Division}" ItemsSource = "{Binding Path=Teams}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:Team}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as when to use what - you can usually tell by what you are overriding. It will be of either the type ControlTemplate or DataTemplate.